# Making a movie clip re-clickable after a video has played in flash as3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, event-handling, movieclip

So I am trying to build a platform where from a menu type page, a user can click a movieclip to watch a video, then after its finished, the video disappears and then they can click another movieclip and this starts another video.

Whenever you watch one video though, all that you can click after the video is finished, is the same movieclip to start it again, you cannot click a different movie clip.

How do I make the other movie clips which start the other videos discoverable? do i need to add a new eventListener that references the other movie clips, and put that within all of the movie clips?

Here is what my code looks like for one of my movie clips

```
taffrail_click_play_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, showTaffrailMovieBox);
taffrail_text_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, showTaffrailMovieBox);

function showTaffrailMovieBox(e:MouseEvent):void
{

    MovieClip(root).taffrail_movie_mc.visible=true; 
    var myTaffTween = new Tween(MovieClip(root).taffrail_movie_mc, "alpha", Strong.easeIn, 0, 1, 1, true);

    var taffVideo:FLVPlayback = new FLVPlayback();
    var myTaffTween1 = new Tween(taffVideo, "alpha", Strong.easeIn, 0, 1, 1, true);
    taffVideo.source = "Wildlife.flv";
    addChild(taffVideo);
    taffVideo.play("Wildlife.flv");

    var cuePt:Object = new Object(); //create cue point object 
    cuePt.time = 3; 
    cuePt.name = "ASpt1"; 
    cuePt.type = "actionscript"; 

    taffVideo.addASCuePoint(cuePt);
    taffVideo.addEventListener(MetadataEvent.CUE_POINT, taff_vid_close);

    function taff_vid_close(eventObject:MetadataEvent):void { 
        var myTaffTween2 = new Tween(taffVideo, "alpha", Strong.easeIn, 1, 0, 1, true);
        var myTaffTween3 = new Tween(MovieClip(root).taffrail_movie_mc, "alpha", Strong.easeIn, 1, 0, 1, true);
        MovieClip(root).taffrail_movie_mc.visible=false;
    }
}
```

Comment: It's very difficult to understand what is going wrong with just this information and nothing else to work with, are you running the debug player have you tried dropping in break points and debugging the code to see where it's breaking down, do you receive any errors, when you click the ones after the first has finished playing does it simply not respond, what about if you add a trace in the handler do you see that trace?

Comment: I don't understand what that means asMan, but it sounds real helpful thanks.
Shaun, as soon as you finish playing one of the videos, its like everything on the screen dissapears apart from the button you click to play that same video. no tried adding a trace, it's just like it is stuck within the play video movie clip, and for lack of a better explanation, is there some function like 'exit movie clip' or 'return to stage' that i can put in at the end of my function that plays the video?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason the other movie clip was not clickable was because I didnt remove the video once it had finished playing, I needed to have

```
myCompbox3.addEventListener(TweenEvent.MOTION_FINISH, removeCompVideo);

    function removeCompVideo(e:TweenEvent):void
{
    removeChild(compVideo);
}
```

within my taff_vid_close function. Thank you, own brain.